# Whats the status of External Master Replication beta in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a compute image that is running a mySql database, with confirmed access to the outside world.

When using the curl script to create an 'interface' to this database no errors are returned. However in the console GUI there is a warning triangle and no read replica can be created.

Are there any known issues with this functionality and/or are there any ways that I could get out some more logging in the response?